# How to apply boundary conditions which are dependent for a system of ODE's in Gekko python?

Tags: gekko

[image]

Boundary conditions are
y1(0)=3;
y2(0)=y1(5)

In the interval of [0,5]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible implementation in Gekko:

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.linspace(0,5)
x = m.Param(m.time)
y1 = m.Var(3)
y2 = m.Var()
m.Connection(y2,y1,'end',1,'end',1)
m.Equation(y1.dt()+2*y1+y2==m.sin(x))
m.Equation(y2.dt()-4*y1-2*y2==m.cos(x))
m.options.IMODE=6
m.solve()
```

However, the solver reports that there is no solution. There are some things that are unclear about your problem statement such as whether the derivative is with respect to `x` or `t`. If `x` is calculated, is is a single value or able to vary throughout the time horizon?

**Edit in response to comment**

You can implement the final conditions `y2(5)=y1(5)` with `m.Connection(y2,y1,'end','end','end','end')`. However, there is no feasible solution to this problem unless you create some type of additional degree of freedom (calculated variable). Without the final condition constraint, there is the unique solution as shown in this figure.

[image: Solution without connection]

When you add the `Connection` final constraint, the solution to the differential equations cannot change and therefore the solver correctly reports too few degrees of freedom.

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.linspace(0,5)
x = m.Param(m.time)
y1 = m.Var(3)
y2 = m.Var()
m.Equation(y1.dt()+2*y1+y2==m.sin(x))
m.Equation(y2.dt()-4*y1-2*y2==m.cos(x))
m.options.IMODE=6
m.Connection(y2,y1,'end','end','end','end')
m.solve()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x.value,y1.value,'r--',label='y1')
plt.plot(x.value,y2.value,'b-',label='y2')
plt.legend(); plt.xlabel('x'); plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Both y1 and y2 are functions of 'x'. There is no time parameter. How can we implement now?

Comment: I am sorry. The boundary conditions are as follows y1(0)=3 and y2(5)=y1(5)